# Use VBscript to paste data into a txt file and save

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I need to paste data from clipboard (Ctrl+V) into a text file and save it.

I already did some research and it seems that a `text file` doesn't have a method like `SaveAs`.

With code below, I could create a new text file and paste data into it, but I can't `Save` it:

```
Set WShshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShshell.run "c:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe",1
WshShell.AppActivate "notepad"
WShshell.SendKeys "^V"
```

I understand there is a method called `CreateTextFile`, but seems I can't perform `paste` with it.

I also tried to combine those two:

```
Set WShshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateTextFile "c:\1.txt",true
WshShell.AppActivate "notepad"
WShshell.SendKeys "^V"
```

But nothing happened...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UFT has its own clipboard access methods you could use.  Here I've created an instance of the clipboard, and extracted its content into `sText`, then created a text file in C:\temp and written the data from the clipboard directly into it.  `oFile.Close` closes the file and saves it at the same time.

```
Dim oClipboard : Set oClipboard = CreateObject("Mercury.Clipboard") 
sText = oClipboard.GetText ' gets the current content of the clipboard

Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile : Set oFile = oFso.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\myTextFile.Txt", True)

oFile.Write sText
oFile.Close
```

Comment: That's some serious cash for functional testing software.

Comment: UFT?  Couldn't tell you, I'm just paid to use it... :)

Comment: @Dave Thanks! I guess I should change Google search keyword to "uft clipboard".... Yesterday I was using "VBscript as keyword"...

Answer (score 3):

I took a stab at it... This was my successful result.

I also noted that this script got really angry when another notepad was already opened.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Set WShshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Gets user profile variable with CMD
UserProfile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c echo.%USERPROFILE%").Stdout.ReadAll

'Creates temporary files in appdata\local\temp
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tmpfilename = fso.GetTempName
tmpfile = Replace(UserProfile & "\AppData\Local\Temp\" & tmpfilename, vbcrlf, "")
Set CreateTempFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(tmpfile, forwriting, true) : CreateTempFile.Close

'Creates a new file for the pasted content
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyFile = ThisFolder & "ClipBoard_Extract_" & _
    Replace(FormatDateTime(Cdate(now),2), "/", "-") & "_" & _
    Hour(now) & Minute(Now) & Second(now) & ".txt"

'Execute's the Main Sub but you could get along without it.
'       I usually build my scripts to scale and do logging and other magical things.
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MainScript

Sub MainScript()
    CaptureClipboardText
    ExtractTempFile
End Sub

Sub CaptureClipboardText
    WShshell.run "c:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe " & tmpfile, 1
    WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
    wscript.sleep 1000
    WShshell.SendKeys "^V"
    WShshell.SendKeys "^S"
    Wshshell.SendKeys "%F"
    Wshshell.SendKeys "x"
    Wshshell.SendKeys "s"
    wscript.sleep 1000
End Sub

Sub ExtractTempFile
    Set Extract = fso.OpenTextFile(tmpfile, ForReading)
    Set Output = fso.OpenTextFile(MyFile, ForWriting, True)  'True on this syntax means - Create the file if it doesn't exist.
    Do Until Extract.AtEndofSTream
        line = Extract.Readline
        Output.Writeline Line
    Loop
    Extract.Close : Set Extract = Nothing
    fso.DeleteFile tmpfile, true
End Sub

Function ThisFolder
    ThisFolder = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, Len(Wscript.ScriptFullName) - Len(Wscript.ScriptName))
End Function
```

### Cheers!

Comment: `tmpfile = fso.BuildPath( WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")("TEMP"), fso.GetTempName)` instead of all that *'Gets user profile variable with CMD* and *literal* `"\AppData\Local\Temp\"`.